# How to get `window.location` on a window opened up using `window.open` not on same Domain

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How to get `window.location` on a window opened up using `window.open` not on same Domain.

I have a newWindow which I need to detect url changes on. From my findings being on different domains could possibly hold me back. Is there a work around?

My html file is on my filesystem.
newWindow is oauth Authorization on Google APIs.

Comment: Doesn't OAuth normally have some kind of callback? Either a URL or JavaScript a function?

Comment: yes, but I am not running this from a server, it's running on a PC now. so I am forced to set my re-direct URI to come back to my browser. I am using : urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob